# An integrable section of the frame bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider the frame bundle $LM$ of a smooth manifold $M$, and a section $X: U \to LM$ evaluated at each point of $U$ consists of $\{X_{1p}, \ldots, X_{np}\}$ a set of basis for $T_PM$. It is integrable if $[X_i, X_j] = 0$. The claim is for $U$ small enough there exists coordinate charts $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ such that $\partial_i = X_i$ if $X$ is integrable.

How do you actually prove it? Just by the definition it is not totally clear that those $X_i$ should be smooth, but it turns out stronger result holds. I know that I am supposed to provide some my own thoughts on it. But I really just do not even know where to start.

Comment: If you want a reference with a full proof, this is Theorem 9.46 (Canonical Form for Commuting Vector Fields) in Lee's intro to smooth manifolds 2ed.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\phi_i$ the local flow of $X_i$. There exists $c>0$ such that ${\phi_i}_t$ is defined if $t\in [-c,c]$. Define, the coordinate at $x$ by $(t_1,...,t_n)={\phi_1}_{t_1}\circ {\phi_2}_{t_2}\circ...\circ {\phi_n}_{t_n}$.

Comment: where does this use the property that the lie bracket vanishes?

Comment: To show that $\partial_i=X_i$, you have to use the fact that the flow of $X_i$ commute.

Comment: Thank you, do you possibly have any reference on this matter?

Comment: Just write the differential, to compute $\partial_i$ you compute ${\partial\over {\partial t_i}}{{\phi_1}_{t_1}\circ...{\phi_n}_{t_n}}_{(0,..,0)}$=${\partial\over{\partial t_i}}{\phi_i}_{t_i}\circ {\phi_1}_{t_1}..\circ {\phi_n}_{t_n}={\partial\over{\partial t_i}}\phi_i$